# Can converting a string to a List<string> be simplified?

Tags: c#

For ease of passing a parameter, I am converting a string to a List.

This is my working example

```
string single = "single";

List<string> list = (new [] {single}).ToList();
```

Can this be shortened?

This attempt is **incorrect** as the list becomes a list of char.

```
List<char> wronglist = single.ToList();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplest would be:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{single};
```

See: [Collection Initializer - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   `IEnumerable`.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to suggest. Likely more efficient as well with fewer intermediary objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that syntax, you could create an Extension method.

```
public static IList<string> ToList(this string) {
    return new List<string>{single};
}
```

Then you could have this with no problems (if there's a conflict with an existing string.ToList(), you can always rename this extension).

```
string single = "single";
List<string> list = single.ToList();
```

Comment: He doesn't want a `List<char>`. he wants a `List<string>`.

Comment: I was looking at his bottom line of code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method, but I'd choose a name besides `ToList` to prevent confusion for items that are enumerable themselves (normally, `single.ToList()` would return a `List<char>`).

```
public static IList<T> AsList<T>(this T single) {
    return new List<T> { single };
}

// e.g.
IList<string> myList = single.AsList();
```